# i would like to read by clicking the text id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jQuery and need help for the following problem.

How can I read the text from div and print in alert at click function?

My html code:

```
<div>
  <div id"test">text1</div> 
  <a href="#">select</a> 

   <div id"test">text2</div>
   <a href="#">select</a> 

   <div id"test">text3</div>
   <a href="#">select</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and put the markup there.  Though what you put in comments, is invalid because of `id"test"` should be `id="test"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('a').on('click', function() {
  var div = $(this).prev();
  alert(div.text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="test1">text1</div> <a href="#">select</a>
  <div id="test2">text2</div> <a href="#">select</a>
  <div id="test3">text3</div> <a href="#">select</a>
</div>
```